# Creating Scheme function that returns a custom map expression

Tags: scheme

Thanks again for your help with my previous scheme questions! I've managed to be able to work through a lot of example questions online with very few hiccups thanks to everybody's help.

Yesterday I created a custom map function that works like the regular map function (or at least I think it does). Today I want to write a function that takes a regular map expression and returns a "my-map" expression.

Here is my definition for my custom map function

```
(define (mymap proc 1st))
```

so my new function would look something like this:

```
(createmymap '(map car '((w x) (y z)))
```

and return this list (It would return the list, not execute the function)

```
(mymap car '((w x) (y z)))
```

I tired to make this as clear as possible but please feel free to ask I know it's a pretty strange question.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks again!

Comment: All you're asking to do is swap out the first element of the list, so you could just do `(cons 'mymap (cdr map-expr))`. You could also use quasiquote.

Comment: Ok I'll see what I can do with this thanks!

Comment: Maybe I cannot get this to work syntactically because I've had a long day of homework (or I'm just stupid) but I can't seem to get this to work with my custom my function "mymap"

Comment: Post what you've tried so far.

Comment: A cooler assignment would to take a map and make a loop that does the same  Eg.  `(convert man '(map proc1 lst1)) => (let ((proc proc1)) (let rec ((lst lst1))...))`